# How configure Angular Azure Static Web App connection to an external .Net Web.Api backend server without Azure Function Proxy - production env

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two different proxy conf. files in angular.json file. One for localhost (working) and another one for production. I have published the client application to the Azure Static Web App but I receive 405 when the client try to call the backend server.
Can Anyone help me to figure out how can i solve this problem?

This is the json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "/api" }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Basically I just needed to go on the Azure Portal > Staic Web App under Settings > APIs and link my Web App. Done this the request is rotued to the backend. at this point can I confirm that no proxy is needed in production.

Comment: Solution above requires paid hosting plan. Wonder if this can be done without an Azure upgrade…